# JSP scriptlet variable To assign to the script variable?

Tags: java, jsp, scriptlet

[image]

After assigning `test.getMethod ()` of test object declared in scriptlet in JSP to String variable text,
What is the method of using text variable in JSP script or using `test.getMethod ()` method separately?

**PS.** This problem should be used on one page. and no use suber&ajax.. sorry

Comment: use <%=test%> .

Comment: More `'<%=test%>'` or `"<%=test.replace("\"", "\\\"")%>"`